# how to make 4 divs take 25/50/100% dynamically when downsized less than their min-width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

lets say you want to display 4 images, of same square dimensions, taking 25% of width. when making the window smaller, make them smaller up to lets say min-width:200px;

BUT, if made any smaller, have the third and fourth image go down below theese first two images and have them take 50% of the space each. theese can be downsized again to min-width:200px;

and if downsized more than 200px again, make it so it displays 1 image taking 100% width each below the last one?

for now i saw and played with something that is almost what i want, but cant quite get it there. any help?

theese are the styles

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
}

.column img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/au53h9jg/

Comment: you need to use a media query I think -that would help you out. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media query to achieve this, here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au53h9jg/2/).

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    width:33.33333333%;
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
}

.column img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
}
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .column {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```